# New Firewall Rule during Azure SQL Login

Tags: azure, authentication

Since yesterday, during login, I get this message:

> New Firewall Rule An error occurred while creating a new firewall rule
>   (HTTP Status Code 409)) (ConnectionDlg)
>
> The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. (System)

Comment: ok, where are you logging into (i assume azure sql)? how?

Comment: Yes. I am logging in Azure Sql (SQL Server management studio) with my credentials. The log in is successful but before it opens, i get that message.

Comment: one thing I'd do go into the portal and delete old rules, maybe you have too much of them. or reinstall SMS. if connection works - nothing to worry about either way

Comment: Thanks, I went to the portal to create a new one. it working.

Comment: 4c74356b41, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in this case manually creating firewall entry fixed this issue

Comment: Deleting the IP entry added by SSMS and manually adding it in the Azure portal worked for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

In case if anybody need further information on this, I able to solve it by removing old useless entries under *Firewalls and virtual networks* section as I hit the maximum firewall rules limit that is 128